# Idea Debugger : Unable to evaluate the expression Method throw 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException' exception

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In the Idea Debugger, the custom Map implementation class has an error with the following error:

> Unable to evaluate the expression Method throw 'java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException' exception

[image]

I don't have a solution。

Comment: The LiteStringMap source: [LiteStringMap.java](https://jlhblog.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/tools/LiteStringMap.java)

Comment: Scanning through your source code it is the `EntrySetWrapper.toArray()` methods that throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. Probably Idea uses these methods when trying to display the contents of the `liteStringMap`. You can test out this idea by returning an empty array instead of throwing `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: Thank you very much，I added the `EntrySetWrapper.toArray` implementation